# Multiple touch responders/actions simultaneously

Tags: react-native

I have 2 pairs of `<View>` inside `<TouchableNativeFeedback>` that act as 2 separate counters that trigger when touched, but I'm not able to touch them simultaneously.

```js
class TouchBox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {counter: 0}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableNativeFeedback style={{flex: 1}} onPress={() => {this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1})}}>
        <View style={this.props.style}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 75}}>{this.state.counter}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableNativeFeedback>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried doing:

```js
<View style={this.props.style} onStartShouldSetResponder={() => {this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 75}}>{this.state.counter}</Text>
</View>
```

but it didn't work.

My main component is:

```js
class TouchTest extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchBox style={{backgroundColor: 'skyblue', width: 200, height: 100, alignItems: 'center'}}/>
        <Text>Test</Text>
        <TouchBox style={{backgroundColor: 'skyblue', width: 200, height: 100, alignItems: 'center'}}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: I would like to be able to touch both of the counters simultaneously and have them work. Right now if I touch one it becomes the only responder and blocks all other touches while my finger is pressed.

Comment: What happens? What do you expect to happen? Giving more details helps others help you better.

Answer (score 0):

View which is outside the TouchableNativeFeedback needs to return true, like this:-

```
<View style={this.props.style} onStartShouldSetResponder={(e) => {this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1}) return true;}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 75}}>{this.state.counter}</Text>
</View>
```